# error information when installing packages

Tags: r

I am puzzled about the following description:

> _ERROR: dependency 'SuppDists' is not available for package 'kSamples'
>
> removing 'F:/R-3.5.1/library/kSamples' In R CMD INSTALL_

Is my edition too old?For I have downloaded one package successfully called"crank" with the option"install package from the local files"
And then the others all failed.

And what about the package which are not released on CRAN Package?
Thanks for answering!

Comment: ould you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

Try installing from CRAN rather than a local download. This is most commonly done using the install.packages command:

```
install.packages("kSamples", dependencies = TRUE)
```

This should take care of any installing dependencies (i.e. other packages that your package needs to function).

If the package is not available from CRAN, then try installing the `devtools` package from CRAN. This will allow you to use other repositories such as Github. To do this you will first need to install and dependencies that the package requires, then install the package you are after.

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools) # load devtools
install_github("username/dependency_repo") # install dependencies
install_github("username/package_repo") # install package
```